# How to call .ashx file in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have .ashx file. How can I call this file in MVC?

Something like this:

```
 <a href="LoadFile.ashx?id=033">load</a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: please share some more of what you already did so we can understand the use-case better

Comment: Unsure what the "issue" is - at the end of the day, its _all ASP.Net_ - you can call a generic handler exactly like your example - and of course deal with the request/response appropriately.

Comment: I find it's call like file, if your ashx file is locate at `\folder1\folder2\yourHandler.ashx`, then you should call it like `http://localhost:3000/folder1/folder2/yourHandler.ashx?varA=xxx&varB=xxx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC does not prevent you from adding a typical ASHX handler. For example here's what I did:

1. Take a new/existing ASP.NET MVC project
2. Right click the project node and select Add -> New -> Generic Handler
3. Name the handler "HandleMe.ashx"
4. Write code in HandleMe.ashx.cs according to what I need the handler to do
5. Run the project and access the handler URL (in my case http://localhost:2951/HandleMe.ashx) and all is good.

For the link you just need to set it to

```
<a href="/HandleMe.ashx">click me</a>
```